# PHP Inserting 15k rows with 2 for loops

Tags: php, mysql, database

I hope you can help me a little bit. I have a JSON file with 653*24 objects and I want to add these into a local database (PHPMyAdmin, Mysql).
I wrote two for loops (first 1 - 654, second 0 - 24) and in those loops I have to insert the information in 6 different tables. I did that, but the problem is that the loops don't insert all ~15k rows, just ~200 and then the loading sign on the browser breaks up and the insert stopps without an error message.

I guess, the inserts are too much for the system, but I don't know so hopefully you guys have an answer/solution for me to solve the problem.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 654; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 24; $j++) {
         *do 6 inserts here*
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I looked at the code again and could it be possible that there is a problem with loading the 653 json links? So because of that it may cause the script ending and not the timeout?

*JSON*

```
https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject={%22page%22:1}
```

*PHP*

```
$db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
$k = 1;
$dataArray = [];

        for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
            for($j = 0; $j < 24; $j++) {

                $json = file_get_contents('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject={%22page%22:' . $i . '}');

                $obj = json_decode($json);

                $id = $k;

                //dbArray
                $playerArray = array("characteristics" => array(),
                    "club" => array(),
                    "nation" => array(),
                    "defending" => array(),
                    "dribbling" => array(),
                    "goalkeeper" => array(),
                    "league" => array(),
                    "pace" => array(),
                    "passing" => array(),
                    "physical" => array(),
                    "player" => array(),
                    "rating" => array(),
                    "shooting" => array());

                $traitArray = array();
                $specialitiesArray = array();
                $specialImageArray = array();
                $attributeArray = array();

                foreach($obj->items[$j]->traits as $value) {
                    array_push($traitArray, $value);
                }
                $traitArray = implode(", ", $traitArray);

                foreach($obj->items[$j]->specialities as $value) {
                    array_push($specialitiesArray, $value);
                }
                $specialitiesArray = implode(", ", $specialitiesArray);

                foreach($obj->items[$j]->specialImages as $value) {
                    array_push($specialImageArray, $value);
                }

                if($specialImageArray[0] != NULL) $obj->items[$j]->headshotImgUrl = $specialImageArray[0];

                foreach($obj->items[$j]->attributes as $key) {
                    array_push($attributeArray, $key->value);
                }

                array_push($playerArray['characteristics'], array(
                    "0" => $obj->items[$j]->firstName,
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->lastName,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->commonName,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->age,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->height . " cm",
                    "5" => "",
                    "6" => "",
                    "7" => "",
                    "8" => $obj->items[$j]->headshotImgUrl,
                    "9" => $obj->items[$j]->position,
                    "10" => $obj->items[$j]->rating,
                    "11" => ucfirst($obj->items[$j]->quality),
                    "12" => ucfirst($obj->items[$j]->color),
                    "13" => $obj->items[$j]->skillMoves,
                    "14" => $obj->items[$j]->weakFoot,
                    "15" => $obj->items[$j]->foot,
                    "16" => $obj->items[$j]->atkWorkRate . " / " . $obj->items[$j]->defWorkRate,
                    "17" => $traitArray,
                    "18" => $specialitiesArray
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['league'], array(
                    "0" => $obj->items[$j]->league->name,
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->league->abbrName,
                    "2" => ""
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['nation'], array(
                    "0" => $obj->items[$j]->nation->name,
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->nation->imageUrls->large
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['club'], array(
                    "0" => $obj->items[$j]->club->name,
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->club->imageUrls->normal->large
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['defending'], array(
                    "0" => $attributeArray[4],
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->interceptions,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->headingaccuracy,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->marking,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->standingtackle,
                    "5" => $obj->items[$j]->slidingtackle
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['dribbling'], array(
                    "0" => $attributeArray[3],
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->agility,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->balance,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->reactions,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->ballcontrol,
                    "5" => $obj->items[$j]->dribbling
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['goalkeeper'], array(
                    "0" => $obj->items[$j]->gkdiving,
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->gkhandling,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->gkkicking,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->gkreflexes,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->sprintspeed,
                    "5" => $obj->items[$j]->gkpositioning
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['pace'], array(
                    "0" => $attributeArray[0],
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->acceleration,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->sprintspeed
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['passing'], array(
                    "0" => $attributeArray[3],
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->vision,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->crossing,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->freekickaccuracy,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->shortpassing,
                    "5" => $obj->items[$j]->longpassing,
                    "6" => $obj->items[$j]->curve
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['physical'], array(
                    "0" => $attributeArray[5],
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->jumping,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->stamina,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->strength,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->aggression
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['shooting'], array(
                    "0" => $attributeArray[1],
                    "1" => $obj->items[$j]->positioning,
                    "2" => $obj->items[$j]->finishing,
                    "3" => $obj->items[$j]->shotpower,
                    "4" => $obj->items[$j]->longshots,
                    "5" => $obj->items[$j]->volleys,
                    "6" => $obj->items[$j]->penalties
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['rating'], array(
                    "0" => "",
                    "1" => "",
                    "2" => "",
                    "3" => "",
                    "4" => "",
                    "5" => "",
                    "6" => ""
                ));

                array_push($playerArray['player'], array(
                    "0" => "",
                    "1" => "",
                    "2" => "",
                    "3" => "",
                    "4" => "",
                    "5" => "",
                    "6" => "",
                    "7" => $obj->items[$j]->isGK
                ));
$values = array(
                        ':id'               => $id,
                        ':charFirstname'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][0],
                        ':charLastname'     => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][1],
                        ':charCommonname'   => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][2],
                        ':charAge'          => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][3],
                        ':charHeight'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][4],
                        ':charNation'       => $playerArray["nation"][0][0],
                        ':charClub'         => $playerArray["club"][0][0],
                        ':charLeague'       => $playerArray["league"][0][0],
                        ':charPicture'      => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][8],
                        ':charPosition'     => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][9],
                        ':charRating'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][10],
                        ':charQuality'      => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][11],
                        ':charColor'        => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][12],
                        ':charSkill'        => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][13],
                        ':charWeak_foot'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][14],
                        ':charStrong_foot'  => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][15],
                        ':charWorkrates'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][16],
                        ':charTraits'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][17],
                        ':charSpecialities' => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][18]);
array_push($dataArray, $values);
$k++;
                }
            }
foreach($dataArray as $values) {

                $data[] = '("' . $values[':id'] . '", "' . $values[':charFirstname'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charLastname'] . '", "' . $values[':charCommonname'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charAge'] . '", "' . $values[':charHeight'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charNation'] . '", "' . $values[':charClub'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charLeague'] . '", "' . $values[':charPicture'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charPosition'] . '", "' . $values[':charRating'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charQuality'] . '", "' . $values[':charColor'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charSkill'] . '", "' . $values[':charWeak_foot'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charStrong_foot'] . '", "' . $values[':charWorkrates'] . '",
                            "' . $values[':charTraits'] . '", "' . $values[':charSpecialities'] . '")';
            }

            $query = 'INSERT INTO characteristics (id, firstname, lastname, commonname, age, height, nation, club, league, picture, position, rating, quality, color, skill, weak_foot, strong_foot, workrates, traits, specialities) VALUES' . implode(',', $data);

            $stmt = $db->createStatement($query);
            $stmt->prepare($query);
            $results = $stmt->execute(array(
                ':id'               => $id,
                ':charFirstname'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][0],
                ':charLastname'     => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][1],
                ':charCommonname'   => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][2],
                ':charAge'          => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][3],
                ':charHeight'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][4],
                ':charNation'       => $playerArray["nation"][0][0],
                ':charClub'         => $playerArray["club"][0][0],
                ':charLeague'       => $playerArray["league"][0][0],
                ':charPicture'      => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][8],
                ':charPosition'     => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][9],
                ':charRating'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][10],
                ':charQuality'      => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][11],
                ':charColor'        => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][12],
                ':charSkill'        => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][13],
                ':charWeak_foot'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][14],
                ':charStrong_foot'  => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][15],
                ':charWorkrates'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][16],
                ':charTraits'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][17],
                ':charSpecialities' => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][18]
            ));
```

Comment: theres a 99.9% chance that your script is timing out try using `set_time_limit(0);` in your loop

Comment: Sounds like you try to execute the queries inside a php script executed in the http server environment. That will not work. Not because those queries create a load the database server cannot handle, that definitely is not an issue. But the execution of php scripts is limited by time, per default to 30 seconds, for security reasons. Just execute the script on command line and all should be fine.

Comment: In addition to what has already been said by @arkascha ,you should always try to optimize your insert queries as much as possible and think if you can arrange it in an array and push it to the db each 200 records or so.

Comment: You can also insert multiple rows in one query using syntax *insert into yourtable (col1,col2...) values (val11,val21...),(val21,val22),...*. This can make it faster avoiding inner loop

Comment: First of all thanks for the comments! I think the problem has something to do with the timeouts. I wrote "set_time_limit(0);" in the loops and set the max_execution_time in php.ini to 1000, but I still get only 473 rows. At least I have to get more rows, even the code isn't that perfect or? I tried also to collect all values in one array without any insert in the loops, but still the script doesn't run full.

Comment: Have you try: set_time_limit(0); in your first line after `<?php`

Comment: Yes, I am trying now to write the code in a separat file, just because I don't know if the framework does something with the timeout.

Comment: I edit something up there, maybe thats the right road for the solution, what do you think?

Comment: If you post the JSON, your actual database query, and more of the PHP, I guarantee someone can come up with a better solution than disabling timeouts. I've got two in mind already.

Comment: There you have it. ;)

Comment: And there you have it! Let me know if anything's not clear but from the brief look at your code I think those suggestions should be valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few resource wasters going on here.

1. You're retrieving the JSON file 24 times more often than you need to. Move the call to `file_get_contents()` out of the inner loop.
2. Prepared statements should be used with this mantra in mind: prepare once, execute many times. Move your statement preparation outside of any loops, and then execute it inside the loops.
3. You're not building a proper prepared statement. The statement is supposed to contain placeholders (either `?` or `:label` format) but you are inserting values into yours. All those parameters you're passing to `execute()` are being ignored. EDIT: Actually, you're inserting every single value on the page 24 times, i.e. you're inserting 24*24 rows for each of the 11 pages.

Summary of suggested changes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO characteristics (
        id, firstname, lastname, commonname, age, height, nation, club, league,
        picture, position, rating, quality, color, skill, weak_foot, strong_foot,
        workrates, traits, specialities
    ) VALUES (
        :id, :charFirstname, :charLastname, :charCommonname, :charAge, :charHeight,
        :charNation, :charClub, :charLeague, :charPicture, :charPosition, :charRating, 
        :charQuality, :charColor, :charSkill, :charWeak_foot, :charStrong_foot, 
        :charWorkrates, :charTraits, :charSpecialities
    )";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject={%22page%22:' . $i . '}');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    for ($j = 0; $j < 24; $j++) {
        //set up your player array
        $results = $stmt->execute(array(
            ':id'               => $id,
            ':charFirstname'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][0],
            ':charLastname'     => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][1],
            ':charCommonname'   => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][2],
            ':charAge'          => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][3],
            ':charHeight'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][4],
            ':charNation'       => $playerArray["nation"][0][0],
            ':charClub'         => $playerArray["club"][0][0],
            ':charLeague'       => $playerArray["league"][0][0],
            ':charPicture'      => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][8],
            ':charPosition'     => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][9],
            ':charRating'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][10],
            ':charQuality'      => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][11],
            ':charColor'        => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][12],
            ':charSkill'        => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][13],
            ':charWeak_foot'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][14],
            ':charStrong_foot'  => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][15],
            ':charWorkrates'    => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][16],
            ':charTraits'       => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][17],
            ':charSpecialities' => $playerArray["characteristics"][0][18]
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the mistake with the json in the inner loop was the main problem.

Comment: You're welcome, but I think inserting 24*24 rows (instead of 24) without any parameterization (also, no protection against injection) is just as much a concern. As the other answer also points out, you're wasting a lot of cycles building arrays you don't need, but this won't be as much a drain as DB and remote data fetching.

Comment: If you've found any of the provided answers helpful, you should vote them up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need refactoring your code. because this

```
 foreach($obj->items[$j]->traits as $value) {
                array_push($traitArray, $value);
 }
```

eqvivalent

```
$traitArray[] = $obj->items[$j]->traits;
```

and json_decode return object way you formating array? I'm don't understand. You can simple get the parameters from this object...
for example you parse haracteristics but you can write him in query

```
':charFirstname'    => $obj->items[$j]->firstName,
':charLastname'     => $obj->items[$j]->lastName,
// and over points
```